# How to set scatter plot x axis values with time data in Excel

Tags: excel

I am learning to use Excel and I collected the the following data:

| age | bedtime |
| --- | --- |
| 25 | 12 AM |
| 55 | 10 PM |
| 58 | 10 PM |
| 47 | 9 PM |
| 52 | 9 PM |
| 35 | 10 PM |
| 37 | 9 PM |
| 34 | 9 PM |
| 24 | 1 AM |
| 24 | 12 AM |
| 29 | 11 PM |
| 24 | 10 PM |

I want to make a scatter chart with the time on the x axis and the age on y. When I select the data manually using the scatter plot option it gives me this:
[scatter chart.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JlAW.png)
I guess excel is pretty confused about the time data.

I want to have the unique values of time on the x axis ordered from earliest to latest like this:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcuB1.png)

I tried making a pivot table because I know how to get unique values from it but Excel was saying I couldn't make a scatter chart with that data. If there is a better way to visualize this data let me know. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sort the data by time then plot.

Comment: What you guess that **excel is pretty confused about the time data** is correct, so you should change the date format in Excel first. Select the time data then change the format to custom formatting `h AM/PM`.

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks for the suggestion but that didn't seem to work, it just gave me the same plot as before when selecting the data. Also when sorting from smallest to largest 12 and 1 AM  occur before 9 PM, which makes sense but I would like those 2 last. I know  I will have to manually sort them somehow but I don't know how, I tried using a PivotTable but it won't let me make a scatter chart from that. Thanks for helping.

Comment: So include date and time, that sorts the time issue.

Comment: @SolarMike that made it work as expected thanks!